# Modify environment variable in a running process

Tags: process, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change environment of a running process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process)

Is there a trick to modify an environment variable in a running process?

I need to add a repository at the end of PATH. I have both access to root and the user of the process (jenkins on tomcat).