# Why can't I print a variable I can see in the output of env?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, environment-variables

I am interested in setting environmental variables of one shell instance from another.
So I decided to do some research.
After reading a [number](https://superuser.com/questions/492146/can-i-change-local-environment-variables-for-a-running-process) of [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process) about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205064/is-there-a-way-to-change-another-processs-environment-variables) I decided to test it out.

I spawned two shells A and B (PID 420), both running `zsh`.
From shell A I ran the following.

```
sudo gdb -p 420
(gdb) call setenv("FOO", "bar", 1)
(gdb) detach
```

From shell B when I run `env` I can see the variable FOO is indeed set with a value of bar.
This makes me think that FOO has been successfully initialised in the environment of shell B.
However, if I try to print FOO I get an empty line implying it is not set.
To me, it feels like there is a contradiction here.

This was tested on both my own Arch GNU/Linux system and an Ubuntu VM.
I also  tested this on `bash` where the variable didn't even show up in env.
This although disappointing for me, makes sense if the shell caches a copy of its environment at spawn time and only uses that (which was suggested in one of the linked questions).
This still doesn't answer why `zsh` can see the variable.

**Why is the output of `echo $FOO` empty?**

---

## EDIT

After the input in the comments I decided to do a bit more testing.
The results can be seen in the tables below.
In the first column is the shell which the `FOO` variable was injected into.
The first row contains the command whose output can be seen below it.
The variable `FOO` was injected using: `sudo gdb -p 420 -batch -ex 'call setenv("FOO", "bar", 1)'`.
The commands specific to zsh: `zsh -c '...'` were also tested using bash.
The results were identical, their output was omitted for brevity.

### Arch GNU/Linux, zsh 5.3.1,  bash 4.4.12(1)

```
|      |  env | grep FOO  | echo $FOO |  zsh -c 'env | grep FOO'  |  zsh -c 'echo $FOO'  |         After export FOO          |
|------|------------------|-----------|---------------------------|----------------------|-----------------------------------|
| zsh  |  FOO=bar         |           | FOO=bar                   | bar                  | No Change                         |
| bash |                  | bar       |                           |                      | Value of FOO visible in all tests |
```

### Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, zsh 5.1.1, bash 4.3.48(1)

```
|      |  env | grep FOO  | echo $FOO |  zsh -c 'env | grep FOO'  |  zsh -c 'echo $FOO'  |         After export FOO          |
|------|------------------|-----------|---------------------------|----------------------|-----------------------------------|
| zsh  |  FOO=bar         |           | FOO=bar                   | bar                  | No Change                         |
| bash |                  | bar       |                           |                      | Value of FOO visible in all tests |
```

The above seems to imply that the results are distribution agnostic.
This doesn't tell me much more than `zsh` and `bash` handle setting of variables differently.
Furthermore, `export FOO` has very different behaviour in this context depending on the shell.
Hopefully these tests can make something clear to somebody else.

Comment: What happens, if you do a `zsh -c 'echo $FOO'` (use single quotes!) instead? Can you see it then?

Comment: The correct value is printed from a new sub shell (tested for bash child also). Clearly the environment is persistent somehow as the child can inherit it but why doesn't the parent honour it?

Comment: That's what I thought. I guess the shell has somewhere a symbol table of variables, some of them are marked as "exported", which means that upon opening a subshell, they are placed into the environment of the child process. Initially (when the shell starts), the variables from the environment at that time are copied into the symbol table (of course also as "exported" variables). When you change the environment, the shell doesn't get noticed to update their symbol table - but child processes (like `env`) see the modified environment.

Comment: I tested on Ubuntu 16.04 with zsh 5.1.1 and bash 4.3.48(1) and it seems setting an environment variable for `zsh` in GDB does not make it visible as a shell variable but does cause it to be passed on to child processes (as you have observed), while setting one for `bash` *does* make it visible as a shell variable but does *not* cause it to be passed on to child processes! It looks like zsh and bash use different strategies for managing variables, with zsh tracking non-environment variables and bash storing everything in its environment which it sanitizes when launching a (non-subshell) child.

Comment: @EliahKagan, interesting; you should post that as an answer.  I also wonder if it makes a difference if you run `export FOO` in `bash`?

Comment: Have you tried "export"ing your variable? When you run a command out spawns another shell so you have to export variables for subprocesses to be able to see them. Hopefully this helps. Didn't post as an answer because i tend to miss details in questions and don't want down votes.

Comment: @KyleH Yes I have. The final column in the added table shows what effect `export FOO` has. In the case of `zsh`, there was no change. For `bash` it made the value of `FOO` visible both within the parent shell and from children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most shells don't use the `getenv()`/`setenv()`/`putenv()` API.

Upon start-up, they create shell variables for each environment variable they received. Those will be stored in internal structures that need to carry other information like whether the variable is exported, read-only... They can't use the libc's `environ` for that.

Similarly, and for that reason, they won't use `execlp()`, `execvp()` to execute commands but call the `execve()` system call directly, computing the `envp[]` array based on the list of their exported variables.

So in your `gdb`, you'd need to add an entry to that shells internal table of variables, or possibly call the right function that would make it interpret a `export VAR=value` code for it to update that table by itself.

As to why you see a difference between `bash` and `zsh` when you call `setenv()` in `gdb`, I suspect that's because you're calling `setenv()` before the shell initialises, for instance upon entering `main()`.

You'll notice `bash`'s `main()` is `int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])` (and `bash` maps variables from those env vars in `envp[]`) while `zsh`'s is `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and `zsh` gets the variables from `environ` instead. `setenv()` does modify `environ` but cannot modify `envp[]` in-place (read-only on several systems as well as the strings those pointers point to).

In any case, after the shell has read `environ` upon startup, using `setenv()` would be ineffective as the shell no longer uses `environ` (or `getenv()`) afterwards.