# Can I specify an arbitrary `$DISPLAY`?

Tags: display

My computer has only one display. Does it correspond to `$DISPLAY` `:0`?

Can an application run on an arbitrary display number, even if I don't see it?

```
$ DISPLAY=:40 firefox
```

Can a X server run on an arbitrary display  number? Will the kernel implicitly create a virtual display?

```
$ xpra start :7
```

Thanks.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503870/what-is-the-relation-between-x-server-and-display. There's no need to mention the kernel

Comment: this question is a mess; fix at least the display specs `:0`, `:40` (both starting with a colon). The kernel does not create any virtual display. You can create a virtual display with `Xvfb :1337`, then run firefox on it with `DISPLAY=:1337 firefox`.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks.  Is a display exactly a socket (and a screen id)? What does "a virtual display " mean?

Comment: No, the same Xserver (aka display) can listen on multiple sockets (by default on linux it's listening on two unix sockets, one file-based and another one abstract; `-listen tcp` will let it also listen on a tcp socket). Also, a xserver/display can have multiple "screens", though nowadays multiple monitors are managed as part of a single "screen". An xserver can use a hardware framebuffer, a dummy framebuffer (`Xvfb`) or a window on another xserver (`Xephyr`). The latter two are examples of "virtual" xserver/displays.

Comment: Do not confuse the actual display (your monitor(s)), the X11 server ("display"), and the way it's accessed via sockets or other means: `DISPLAY=:0` and `DISPLAY=localhost:10` as forwarded via ssh refer to the same display/xserver, the same video card, and the same monitor.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks. (1) "by default on linux it's listening on two unix sockets, one file-based and another one abstract;" Do you mean an unbound unix socket by "abstract"? What purposes does X server use the two sockets for respectively?

Comment: @mosvy. (2) "Do not confuse the actual display (your monitor(s)), the X11 server ("display"), and the way it's accessed via sockets or other means: DISPLAY=:0 and DISPLAY=localhost:10 as forwarded via ssh refer to the same display/xserver, the same video card, and the same monitor."  I am still confused actually. Does `$DISPLAY` specify both a listening socket and a rendering target at the same time?

Comment: An [abstract unix socket](https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract%20unix%20socket&btnG=Search&gl=en&hl=en) is a socket which is bound to a simple byte sequence instead of a file system object. It's something that only exists on Linux, but on Linux it's the **default** for an X11 client to first try to connect to an abstract unix adresss, and then to a path.

Comment: (2) No, `$DISPLAY` does not specify a "rendering target". And no need to harp about what "rendering target" means -- XrandR is able to let a root window (screen) span multiple monitors rendered to through **multiple GPUs**. The "screen" part of the display spec (the second number of the `$DISPLAY`) will determine what the `DefaultScreen()` and `DefaultRootWindow()` X11 library functions will return. Unless you're using an Xserver configured with multiple old-style screens (with multiple root windows), that number should be omitted or 0.

Comment: And nowadays there's 0 reason to configure an Xserver with multiple screens/root-windows, unless there's some hardware incompatibility (eg. multiple video cards with different depths). In the case of modern X11 server, where the same root window can be rendered through multiple GPUs on multiple monitors, an application window can be rendered on multiple "rendering targets" at the same time, or you can simply grab it with the mouse and move it from one "rendering target" to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify an arbitrary display, but you won’t get far if there’s no corresponding X server. The display number is specified when the X server is started, by whatever starts the X server — typically your display manager, or yourself in your Xpra example. It’s :0 by default (see [the `Xserver` manpage](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.html)). It can be chosen arbitrarily, but the X server won’t start if the corresponding resources aren’t available (port 6000 + the display number if it’s configured to listen on TCP, `/tmp/.X11-unix/X` followed by the display number if it’s configured to listen on a Unix domain socket, etc.). The kernel isn’t involved.

Comment: Thanks. "the corresponding resources aren’t available (port 6000 + the display number if it’s configured to listen on TCP)". Is the corresponding resources only TCP port? Is it by default configured to listen on TCP?

Comment: See my update. The defaults depend on your system; typically X listens on TCP and domain sockets, but many setups now disable TCP (with the `-nolisten tcp` option).

Comment: Thanks. Does "staring a X server at display n" means exactly starting a X server which listens at a port 6000+n (Unix or TCP domain socket)? No more no less?

Comment: Notice that there's no port number for Unix domain sockets

Comment: @Tim **a)** the current X11 servers do not listen on tcp by default (you'll have to force them to with `-listen tcp` **b) unix sockets have no ports**. If you start an X11 server with `Xorg :2000000000`, it will create and listen on an unix socket in `/tmp/.X11-unix/X2000000000` (and also on an abstract socket with the same name in Linux). The limit for a display number is MAX_INT when listening on a Unix socket, and `65535-6000=59535` when listening on tcp.

Comment: Stephen Kitt, does `$DISPLAY` specify  a listening socket, a rendering target, or both?  I am confused.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505996/does-display-specify-both-a-listening-socket-and-a-rendering-target-at-the-sa

Comment: "It can be chosen arbitrarily, but the X server won’t start if the corresponding resources aren’t available"  Does "resource" mean rendering target e.g. monitor?

Comment: `DISPLAY` only specifies a value for the `XOpenDisplay()` function; see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467487/86440) for details. The resources which need to be available are listed between parentheses just after the part you’ve quoted.