# Does X11 forwarding create a "new" X11 session?

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

I've been using X11 forwarding to forward clipboard contents from remote servers.

When I tried to use X11 forwarding from one GUI linux computer to another, I noticed something peculiar. Let's say that machine A sshs into machine B.

I can issue the following command on any machine to check its clipboard contents

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o
```

I see the same clipboard contents when I issue it on `A` and on the ssh prompt connected from `A` to `B`.

However, if I issue it on machine `B`'s GUI session, then I see different contents!

Does this mean that machine `B` has two X11 sessions? One for the GUI, and one created when I ssh'd into it via `A`?

Since on linux everything is a file, where do files for these respective sessions live?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you forward an X11 connection, you give the remote system access to your local X11 session (through SSH). Thus, when you connect to B from A, with X11 forwarding enabled, the programs you run in that SSH session are connected to your X11 session on A. This explains why `xclip` shows the same contents on A and in the SSH session from A to B.

The X11 session on B is separate, and isn’t connected to A or your SSH session.

There are two X11 sessions, but not on B: one on A, one on B.

X11 sessions “live” in the X11 server, they’re not stored in files.

Comment: This makes sense. However, shouldn't it be the case that A's X11 session lives on A but is being "exposed" to B through some files (or socket file)? Also your answer prompts an additional question: is it *possible* for a machine to *have* multiple X11 sessions of their own?

Comment: With SSH X11 forwarding, it’s exposed over TCP; on B, look for a process listening on port 6010 (or [6000 + whatever your `DISPLAY` is set to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505941/86440)). A single machine can have multiple X11 sessions: multiple X11 servers can run on a single machine.