# Why can't I start a GUI program on the default `$DISPLAY` on a remote ssh server host?

Tags: ssh, x11, display

I ssh to a remote host (without X forwarding).

In the shell created by sshd on the remote host, why can't I start a GUI program on the default `$DISPLAY`

```
$ eog
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(eog:31542): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:11:16.793: cannot open display: 

$ echo "$DISPLAY"

$
```

while specifying explicitly `$DISPLAY=:0` creates  a window on the remote host?

```
$ DISPLAY=:0 eog

(eog:31546): dbind-WARNING **: 23:11:42.415: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
```

Isn't `:0`  the default value of `$DISPLAY`?

Comment: Are you SSH port forwarding the X port to your local host?

Comment: Why would an env has default value? If it doesn't exist, then it doesn't exist, and so you can't retrieve it. If it exist, then it has some value, might be empty string, but it has some value.

Comment: Really don't know what do you mean by "default `$DISPLAY`". Please use `env` command to check all your envs.

Comment: If you mean some sort of API that allows you to retrive a default value when some environment variable doesn't exist, I don't think xlib or xcb or any X client would use such API. So, if there's no $DISPLAY and you don't specify the display for your X client by some method, it simply fails to connect to any Display

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no default value for `DISPLAY`. If it’s not set, and you don’t specify a target display in some other way, X programs won’t be able to connect to a server.

This can be useful, *e.g.* to start a program with no X connection when you’re running inside an X session: temporarily clearing `DISPLAY` will ensure the X session isn’t found.

See [How to change DISPLAY of currently running application](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402381/86440) for details of how `DISPLAY` is used, and [Open a window on a remote X display (why "Cannot open display")?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10121/86440) for details of the information required to connect to an X server.

Comment: That's exactly what I said in the comment. But I can't figure it out how is this useful for a X-based GUI program that you prevent it finding a Display?

Comment: Some programs support X optionally; examples include Emacs (where you can achieve the same effect with `-nw`) and Wine. Clearing `DISPLAY` disables X support. It’s useful with Wine because running window-less tests is faster with no `DISPLAY` set.

Comment: Thanks. (1) I heard somthing like `$DISPLAY` defaults to `:0.0`. Did I mishear it? What is it instead? (2)   "If you ssh onto some server, **usually** the display will be set automatically to the local X server, if there is one available. Otherwise, it will not be set at all (reason see terminal 3)." https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503884/. But your reply seems to say usually `DISPLAY`  is no set

Comment: (1) **There is no default.** (2) I’m not sure what suggests that to you, it’s usually set when you’re running in an environment where connecting to an X server makes sense.