# export env variables from file in a makefile

Tags: environment-variables, make

I'm trying to write a make task that will export all variables from my 
.env file, which should look like this:

```
A=1
B=2
```

If I type in terminal:

```
set -a
. ./.env
set +a
```

it works perfectly.

But same task in Makefile doesn't work:

```
export.env:
    set -a
    . ./.env
    set +a


make export.env # done
printenv | grep A # nothing!
```

I need these vars to persist after make task finished.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like any process, `make` [can’t modify the environment of an existing process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38205/86440), it can only control the environment which is passed to processes it starts. So short of stuffing the input buffer, there’s no way to do what you’re trying to do.

In addition, `make` processes each command line in a different shell, so your `set -a`, `. ./.env`, and `set +a` lines are run in separate shells. The effects of `. ./.env` will only be seen in the shell which runs that command.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer does not help the person who send the question. See my answer for a hint on how to do it.

Comment: @schily I don’t see how your answer helps, given that the OP said “I need these vars to persist after make task finished.”

Comment: OK, I did not see this and the header does not mention that the question was not related to the make, but asks for help with make.

Answer (score 6):

Modern `make` implementations include support for managing the environment.

GNU make does, my `smake` does and my enhanced version of `SunPro Make` that is available in the `schilytools` tarball supports it.

If you carefully write your `env` file to have assignments and `export` statements on different lines, you can `include` the `env` file in your `Makefile`.

Use e.g.:

```
include $(HOME)/.env
```

in your `Makefile`.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted but adding `-include /path/to/.env` to Makefile works well for me.